Dual boot Ubuntu - Lost data when I booted from windows
I have a HP Probook 450 G5 laptop, and I have a dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10
The problem is after a while time of using Ubuntu and read/write from Partitions on windows (D: and E:)
I have decided to reboot from windows for a specific task, but when I tried to access files that have been modified on D: from Ubuntu, I do not find them and the partition prompted that the disk need to be checked.
I noticed that, the files have been deleted were the files that latest accessed from apps on ubuntu
like the latest file was opened by VSCode, the latest PDF, the Latest video has been accessed and so on.
What is the problem?

In simple words: Windows is keeping "secrets" (hiding information) from Ubuntu. Unless you turn OFF windows completely (no hibernation, or fastboot) before using Ubuntu you will get this kind of problems.
